# Blank field getting set as the highest value in top 6 in R even after using is.na()

Tags: r, tidyverse, na, lubridate

I used is.na() to clear out missing fields in my data frame, also checked it as below:

```
[1] "Number of Missing Values 334920"
[1] "Number of Missing Values 0"
[1] "Number of Rows 4324489"
```

but later when im trying to find the top 6 stations with the highest count of rides using the head(), im seeing the number one field is that of blank station name which has the highest count.

```
top_5_start_stations <- total_trips_v2 %>%
  group_by(member_casual="casual", start_station_name) %>%
  summarize(number_of_rides =n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(number_of_rides)) %>%
  head()
```

I even tried to check for N/A values again in that column specifically, using the

```
which(is.na(total_trips_v2$end_station_name), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

but even that gave

```
integer(0)
```

which means there are no missing values.

Linking my code here:
https://github.com/Davesarthak787/Cyclistic-Bike-Share/blob/main/Cyclistic%20Case%20Study.Rmd

minimum dataset given below:

```
structure(list(ride_id = c("C66CC4DD911DDFBD", "BD6363747C00FAD3", 
"1856297CBD809E60", "06B27D89815F5031", "7F17B8FF6F418A7F", "78DDAA9DC15B9F88", 
"37C8130AFB1CD5D9", "1F12C2078695D31C", "A35D396058FEB2FC", "B7690A39BCF903C0", 
"3B19438FA129A52D", "E5A062F8607CA4F5", "52EA2729B619299E", "F265530E5DEC17C4", 
"C1572B6F020EB22D", "A22193BD57B96AA9", "1FDD7F2370ABF00F", "0883650D73C5E765", 
"2144B1A1B6AF3131", "A8A0101C605A719A"), rideable_type = c("docked_bike", 
"docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", 
"docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", 
"docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", 
"docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike", "docked_bike"), 
    started_at = structure(c(1593561600, 1593561600, 1593561600, 
    1593561600, 1593561660, 1593561660, 1593561660, 1593561720, 
    1593561720, 1593561720, 1593561720, 1593561720, 1593561720, 
    1593561780, 1593561780, 1593561780, 1593561780, 1593561780, 
    1593561780, 1593561840), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    ended_at = structure(c(1593566880, 1593571440, 1593564300, 
    1593571920, 1593562080, 1593563040, 1593565020, 1593563160, 
    1593563160, 1593563760, 1593571680, 1593563760, 1593561780, 
    1593562980, 1593562980, 1593562380, 1593562620, 1593562980, 
    1593562320, 1593561960), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    start_station_name = c("Buckingham Fountain", "Wells St & Concord Ln", 
    "Wabash Ave & Wacker Pl", "Wells St & Concord Ln", "State St & 33rd St", 
    "Clark St & Grace St", "Lake Shore Dr & Monroe St", "Rush St & Cedar St", 
    "Rush St & Cedar St", "Michigan Ave & Lake St", "Wells St & Concord Ln", 
    "Michigan Ave & Lake St", "Sedgwick St & Webster Ave", "Ashland Ave & Division St", 
    "Ashland Ave & Division St", "Ashland Ave & Division St", 
    "Sheffield Ave & Wellington Ave", "Federal St & Polk St", 
    "Sedgwick St & Webster Ave", "Winthrop Ave & Lawrence Ave"
    ), end_station_name = c("Buckingham Fountain", "Clark St & Lake St", 
    "Wabash Ave & Wacker Pl", "Clark St & Lake St", "MLK Jr Dr & 29th St", 
    "Clark St & Elmdale Ave", "Lake Shore Dr & Monroe St", "Rush St & Cedar St", 
    "Rush St & Cedar St", "Millennium Park", "Clark St & Lake St", 
    "Millennium Park", "Sedgwick St & Webster Ave", "Rush St & Cedar St", 
    "Rush St & Cedar St", "Campbell Ave & North Ave", "Clarendon Ave & Leland Ave", 
    "Laflin St & Cullerton St", "Sedgwick St & Webster Ave", 
    "Sheridan Rd & Lawrence Ave"), member_casual = c("casual", 
    "casual", "casual", "casual", "member", "member", "casual", 
    "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", 
    "member", "member", "member", "casual", "casual", "casual", 
    "member"), ride_length = c(5280, 9840, 2700, 10320, 420, 
    1380, 3360, 1440, 1440, 2040, 9960, 2040, 60, 1200, 1200, 
    600, 840, 1200, 540, 120), date = structure(c(18444, 18444, 
    18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 
    18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18444
    ), class = "Date"), month = c("07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
    "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
    "07", "07", "07", "07", "07"), day = c("01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01"), year = c("2020", 
    "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
    "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2020", 
    "2020", "2020", "2020"), day_of_week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
    "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Im not being able to fix this.

Can anyone tell me how to go about this?

Comment: Can you show the `NA` values in your data? I think those are not real `NA` values but string "NA". It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I would like to create a small reproducible data, but how do i get my data to be loaded here? Sorry, Im new to stackoverflow so not really well versed with it. 
Apart from the data, should  I paste the code starting from loading packages to mentioning the code to just make this chunk of code work, which im facing an issue with?

Comment: Run `dput(head(total_trips_v2, 20))` in the console, copy the output and edit your post to include it here. In this way we can use your data as it is directly. Only keep relevant columns important for the question in `total_trips_v2` before running the `dput` command.

Comment: @RonakShah alright i did that as you instructed! Lemme know what do you think is the issue

Comment: I'm not seeing a blank name at the top - Ashland Ave & Division St comes up top.

Comment: This is good. Thanks. But the issue is in this 20 rows there is no blank field or `NA` value that you are referring in the question. You need to provide a subset which has those values.

Comment: @RonakShah thats the issue right, how will i find those subsets, because its not showing up when im using the is.na() , if i knew that subset i wouldve removed it in the first place.